# Customer Portal User foreign key in Contacts?

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object

When enabling Customer Portal access for a Contact, Salesforce creates a new Portal User for the person. I am creating an apex trigger for when the user creates a record in an object and would like to refer to information found in their related Contact and Parent Account records.

I believe the foreign keys are stored in the Contacts object (Contact to User), but I'm not sure what the field is called. Could someone help me identify the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the ID of the `Contact` that is stored in the `User` object `ContactId` field and the relationship is called `Contact`.